# Combine rows on django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a querset with attributes location, person and error

I need to either create a new queryset or edit an existing one such that rows are "combined" based on a certain criteria
This criteria is if the location and person are the same
Once combined, I want to make the error value be true if any of the rows that are being combined had a true value
In this case the table should be changed as follows:

| Location | Person | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | P1 | false |
| L1 | P1 | true |
| L2 | P2 | false |
| L2 | P2 | false |

| Location | Person | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | P1 | true |
| L2 | P2 | false |

Comment: What is the goal and on what criteria do you want to filter the queryset or groupby? Do you want to filter more into in result or you want to filter in different querysets?

Comment: I think my tables were unclear. I wanted to filter the first table into the second one

Comment: And what would be the filtering criteria? you can always apply filter() on existing queryset. Can you explain in detail what exactly you want to achieve? Like what do you want to combine?

Comment: I'm combining rows if they have the same location and person values

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `aggregate()` for this purpose, but `annotate()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate)).

Input:

```
class T(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    error = models.BooleanField()

T.objects.bulk_create([
    T(person='P1', location='L1', error=False),
    T(person='P1', location='L1', error=True),
    T(person='P2', location='L2', error=False),
    T(person='P2', location='L2', error=False)
])
for t in T.objects.all().values('person', 'location').distinct().annotate(error=Sum('error')):
    print(t)
```

Output:

```
{'person': 'P1', 'location': 'L1', 'error': True}
{'person': 'P2', 'location': 'L2', 'error': False}
```

Comment: What happens to the error values in T.objects.all().values('person', 'location').distinct()? The values at this point don't "remember" all the error values for each unique person, location pair. Also I'm unable to use Sum or Max on boolean values.

Comment: In your head, you are splitting `T.objects.all().values('person', 'location').distinct().annotate(error=Sum('error'))` into `T.objects.all().values('person', 'location').distinct()` and `annotate(error=Sum('error'))`, and think that the errors are already lost when the first part gets evaluated. However, this is not how Django works. The queryset only gets evaluated when you need the results, and at that moment, Django already knows it needs to aggregate  the error values according to the second part.

Comment: You can use Sum on boolean values, both in Django and Python itself. I have tested the Sum used in my answer on my local machine (using Django 3.2). Example in Python: ```>>> bool(sum([True, True, False]))
True
>>> bool(sum([False, False]))
False```

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughtful responses. Where can I learn about this property of django where as you say 'queryset only gets evaluated when you need the results, and at that moment, Django already knows it needs to aggregate the error values according to the second part'

Comment: If you want to learn about it, a good start would be the official docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). To understand the impacts of it, I suggest to play around with some simple toy models in different scenarios to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so to help you out you can do this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(your query).values('location', 'person').distinct()
```

by using .distinct() no duplicates will be present and you shall achieve what you want. (which also serves the purpose if location and person are the same for 2 rows)

Comment: When I use distinct, what happens to the issue attribute?

Comment: you can remove values and place both fields in .distinct('location', 'person')

Comment: I still need to be thinking about the Error attribute. Remember, if any of the same ('location', 'person') pairs has an error I need to make note of it.